# How do I highlight specific letters in the text of a QListWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, css, qt, qt5

I am writing a search algorithm that searches a QListWidget and returns relevant matches based on what the user types in the search bar.  I would like any matches to be highlighted in a yellowish color.

For example:

If the user types "ilt" into the search bar, I would like to highlight the corresponding letters that are in the QListWidgetItem with the text "Write F**ilt**er" (bolded, for convenience).

Assuming that I have access to both phrases and can programmatically identify which letters in the QListWidgetItem text that I need to highlight, is there an API or algorithm that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you have to create a custom delegate that paints the text the way you want. You can read about it [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/27777-Customize-QListWidgetItem-how-to).

But if you want to customize a `QListWidget` you can simply use the `QListWidget::setItemWidget` method:

```
QListWidget *list = new QListWidget;

QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(list);

QLabel *label = new QLabel("my <span style=\"color: red\">red</span> text");
list->setItemWidget(item, label);
```